# Кодировка в консоли

Tags: python

Писал я значит мессенджер, простенький, уже в конце столкнулся с тем, что когда один пользователь пишет, другой не получает, а на сервер отправляется, что он написал **"A12!@#^&!@#$!@"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь код клиентской части:

```
import socket, threading, time

key = 8194

shutdown = False
join = False


def receiving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                # print(data.decode("utf-8"))

                decrypt = ""; k = False
                for i in data.decode("utf-8"):
                    if i == ":":
                        k = True
                        decrypt += 1
                    elif k == False or i == " ":
                        decrypt += i
                    else:
                        decrypt += chr(ord(i) ^ key)
                print(decrypt)

                time.sleep(0.2)

        except:
            pass


host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 0

server = ("Здесь ip", 139)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

alias = input('Name: ')

rT = threading.Thread(target=receiving, args=('RecvThread', s))
rT.start()

while shutdown == False:
    if join == False:
        s.sendto(("[" + alias + "])) => join chat ").encode("utf-8"), server)
        join = True
    else:
        try:
            message = input()

            crypt = ""
            for i in message:
                crypt += chr(ord(i) ^ key)
            message = crypt

            if message != "":
                s.sendto(("["+alias + "] :: " + message).encode("utf-8"), server)

            time.sleep(0.2)
        except:
            s.sendto(("["+alias + "] <= left chat ").encode("utf-8"), server)
            shutdown = True

rT.join()
s.close()
```

Серверной части:

```
import socket
import time

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 139

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))

quit = False
print("[ Server Started ]")

while not quit:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)

        itsatime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", time.localtime())

        print("[" + addr[0] + "]=[" + str(addr[1]) + "]=[" + itsatime + "]/", end='')
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))

        for client in clients:
            if addr != client:
                s.sendto(data, client)
    except:
        print("\n[ Server Stopped ]")
        quit = True

s.close()
```

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не в консоли, а в кодировании/декодировании ксором при передаче. Попробуйте проверить, будет ли нормально передаваться без ксора.

Comment: Не получилось, все равно :(

Comment: Ох такое маленькое приложение а уже не читаемо :) Не стал разбираться что и как у вас там но общий принцип такой. Вы получаете из консоли (?) текст. Разбираете его на байты 'текст'.encode при этом необходимо указать в какой кодировке исходный текст (скорее всего Вы этого не знаете тут и кроется ошибка)  затем перекодировать его в кодировку которую понимает сервер. Что бы узнать исходную кодировку напишите в комментарии исходный текст и "кракозябры" до отправки на сервер.

Comment: Вообще каша. По нормальному нужно структурировать пакеты, а не всё в одно. Тут проблема скорее всего в неверной декодировки сообщения

Answer (score 0):

Если не можете разобраться с кодировкой используйте 2cyr
https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru

Далее используйте

`str.encode(encoding="ваша кодировка")`
Для кодирования или
`str.decode(encoding="ваша кодировка")` для декодированния

Где str любая строковая переменная.

Comment: Тут не нужно угадывать кодировку, там на одной стороне кодируется utf-8, на другой - декодируется utf-8. Правда на клиенте еще ответ сервера декодируется как будто он должен был быть зашифрован ксором, а на сервере я не вижу, чтобы что-то кодировалось.